# Is there any way to remove the 10 recipents limit from the SMS app?

Tags: applications, sms, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Can you actually do this? I know that there are some apps where you can send SMS to a unlimited number of recipients, but I would prefer to remove the limit of the built-in SMS app. My phone is a *Samsung Galaxy Note II* (rooted).

Comment: Since your phone is rooted you can install the Xposed framework (check out https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ma.wanam.xposed&hl=en) and there is a module for 'SMS recipients' so you can override the max limit in this. It's an amazing piece of kit an lets you tweak virtually anything in your current stock (or cusom) ROM. Visit the XDA thread for full details: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2383484

Comment: @RossC, That seems like a solid answer to me. I think it deserves to be posted as such =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your phone is rooted you can use  [Wanam Xposed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ma.wanam.xposed&hl=en)

Note that the framework itself doesn't add any functionality, but once installed you can download (via the framework itself) modules that have custom functionality. Wanam Xposed module has many tweaks for stock Samsung Touchwiz ROMs, GravityBox has many for morer 'stock' type ROMs. You can change the SMS limit through either, in the default SMS application.

Please read the XDA Thread on this module as it has a lot of detail, and clarifications.
 [XDA Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2383484)