# Send SMS to a list of recipients from a text file

Tags: sms

I am  old user of Nokia E72 and it has got an interesting function that I always used.

But now I moved to Android on an Xperia SL. On my Nokia, the field of recipients allowed me to copy and past the list of contacts separated by linebreak, from a text file.

This worked with even more than 500 contacts at once.

Unfortunately, I cannot do this on my new Xperia.

My Question is: Which SMS App can allow me to send SMS to a list of recipients from a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Android has a 10-recipient limit for SMS messages to prevent abuse. With root access, you can bypass this limitation. See: [Is there any way to remove the 10 recipents limit from the SMS app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59571/is-there-any-way-to-remove-the-10-recipents-limit-from-the-sms-app)